# Magento - crypt module is not initialized

Tags: magento, module, payment, mcrypt

I'm getting an error "Crypt module is not initialized" when I try to access to system->config->payment methods section.

Mcrypt php module is installed and loaded.

Does anyone know about this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you know the Mcrypt module is installed ..? And describe more about your server environment ..

Comment: I've checked it through the phpinfo. Version of PHP is 5.5.3, I'm using apache and mysql